# global varibales from another js

Tags: javascript, webpack

my webpack.config.js file is as follow

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
        './js/config.js',
        './js/app.js'
    ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './js/app.bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    library: 'ui'
  }
};
```

my config.js file has global variable baseURL which app.js is using 
config.js file

```
var hostname_ = window.location.hostname;
var port_ = window.location.port;
var baseURL = "http://" + hostname_ + ":"+ port_ + "/admin/";

module.exports = {
  baseURL: baseURL
};
```

in browser i am getting error

```
ReferenceError: baseURL is not defined
```

Comment: What does your `app.js` file contain? How are you importing and using `baseURL`?

Comment: Tired calling it directly baseURL and also treid ui.baseURL both gives undefined

Comment: Can you add the code from that file in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Import baseURL in app.js:

```
import baseURL from './config'
```

or:

```
var baseURL = require('./config')
```

Comment: Ok did that but now gettings error in browser TypeError: "exports" is read-only
app.bundle.js:11946:5
TypeError: ui is undefined

Comment: For me it works. I notice you have library and libraryType options, try 
to remove from output settings of webpack.

Comment: The same error? Do you reference 'ui' somewhere in app.js?

Comment: Yes I was calling a function from html like ui.functionname now when I remove ui. I am getting functionname not defined also getting export is read-only

Comment: At the end of app.js I do have module.exports = {
  funcationname: funcationname
};

Comment: a wrong name funcationname (!=functionname) here or in code?

Comment: I did a quick search and found a related issue: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3997 As a quick experiment try to use require if you are using import from 'baseURL'

Comment: Try also to change module.exports = {functionname:functionname} with export default {functionname:functionname}. for reference: https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue-pdf/issues/2